# Attempt to present uiview controller on uinavigationcontroller whose view is not in the windows hierarchy

Tags: ios

I have two view controller: first login and second is main view controller. When i try to present the login view controller in `appdelegate` class then i get this following warning:

`2013-06-24 04:44:42.158 scrumptious[4506:19a03] Warning: Attempt to present <SCLoginViewController: 0x9490800> on <UINavigationController: 0x948b0d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set login as rootview after successful login replace root view as your desired view

Comment: have you imported SCLoginViewController in appdelegate.m

Comment: yes sir, i did that , i have 3 classes SCAppDelegate,SCLoginViewController,SCViewController, and two SCLoginViewController.xib and SCViewController.xib, in SCAppDelegate i wrote the code of 10 lines like- (void)showLoginView
{
    UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navController topViewController];
    
    SCLoginViewController* loginViewController =
    [[SCLoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SCLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    [topViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
    
    
} then i called this then i get error

Comment: #import "SCAppDelegate.h"

#import "SCViewController.h"

#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>//

#import "SCLoginViewController.h"//

Comment: but i m doing this from the tutorial which is linkhttp://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/ , i m following this link to make the app

Answer (score 1):

Try to Present main from first not app delegate

Comment: but i m doing this from the tutorial which is linkhttp://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/ , i m following this link to make the app